# Tuple of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python. Below code works fine.

```
tup1 = ('A', 'B')
tup2 = ('C', 'D')
f = tup1, tup2
for i, j in f:
    print(i,j)
```

But is there is only one tuple in it. It will not work. Any reason why? Thanks in advance

```
tup1 = ('A', 'B')
f = tup1
for i, j in f:
    print(i,j)
```

I am expecting result like below.
A B

Comment: hi welcome , can you provide input/output expected

Comment: It's not clear why you don't expect a tuple to be different from a tuple of tuples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f = tup1
```

Does not create a tuple. Try this:

```
f  = (tup1,) # extra comma at the end
```

Full code:

```
tup1 = ('A', 'B')
f = (tup1,)
for i, j in f:
    print(i,j)
```

Output:

```
A B
```

Comment: Obligatory reminder that it's the comma that creates the tuple, not the parentheses. `f = tup1,` has the same result.

Comment: This worked! I was thinking the above will make f= (('A', 'B')) . Got it now. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

The code you're writing in only works if there are two items for each index in tup1. For example, if this were to be the case:

```
    random1 = ('a','b')
    random2 = (3,4)
    tup1 = (random1, random2)
    f = tup1
```

And then if you used the same loop you had, it would spit out 'a' and 'b' and then 3 and 4. If you're intentions are to just spit out the contents in f, then the following code should do the trick:

```
    tup1 = ('A', 'B')
    f = tup1
    for i in f:
        print(i)
```

Comment: The answer given by rdas and chepner did the trick. I wanted to print tuple of tuple which has 2 entries each, which will be created by the code. The issue was for printing the result when there is only one tuple in it. Adding a "," did the trick! New learning everyday!

Comment: Glad you got your solution!